# Why does SSH dynamicforward result in some kind of loop leading to "too many open files" error

Tags: ssh, proxy

I would like to understand why my SSH client gives me this error:

```
channel 1017: open failed: connect failed: open failed
channel 1017: open failed: connect failed: Too many open files
channel 1017: open failed: connect failed: Too many open files
channel 1017: open failed: connect failed: Too many open files
```

Background:

I have my webbrowser configured to use localhost:6162 as a socks proxy, and use SSH to provide this proxy by using `ssh -d6162 hostname`.

Normally this is connected to a remote server, and in that case it works as intended. But some websites require me to connect from my own country, which my server is not.

Because it is not easy to reconfigure the browser Proxy everytime I need such a website, I disconnect the ssh client, and start a new one with `ssh -d6162 127.0.0.1`

In theory, this should just replace the proxy the browser sees with a different endpoint, and I would it expect to just behave the same.

This is not the case though, and instead, the ssh client starts throwing `too many open files' error and the connection dies after a couple seconds.

If I start ssh with `-vvv`, I can see that as soon as I start it, the (ssh?) client generates connections until the max-open-files is reached:

```
debug1: channel 993: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38054 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636, nchannels 24
debug3: channel 993: status: The following connections are open:
  #993 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38054 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r989 i0/0 o3/0 fd 999/999 cc -1)
  #994 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38056 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r990 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1000/1000 cc -1)
  #995 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38058 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r991 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1001/1001 cc -1)
  #996 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38060 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r992 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1002/1002 cc -1)
  #997 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38062 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r993 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1003/1003 cc -1)
  #998 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38064 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (
debug1: channel 994: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38056 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636, nchannels 23
debug3: channel 994: status: The following connections are open:
  #994 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38056 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r990 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1000/1000 cc -1)
  #995 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38058 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r991 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1001/1001 cc -1)
  #996 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38060 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r992 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1002/1002 cc -1)
  #997 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38062 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r993 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1003/1003 cc -1)
  #998 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38064 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636 (t4 r994 i0/0 o3/0 fd 1004/1004 cc -1)
  #999 direct-tcpip: listening port 34636 for 127.0.0.1 port 34636, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38066 to 127.0.0.1 port 34636
```

This goes on until the ulimit for files is reached.
I think I am unintentionally creating some kind of loop so that every connection the browser is creating is creating another connection, which is creating another connection which is creating another connection etc..

Again, this only happens with a dynamicforward to `localhost`, in my normal use case connection to a remote server it works perfectly.

ssh client and server:
`OpenSSH_7.5p1 Debian-10, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017`

browser: `Google Chrome 61.0.3163.91`

browser config:

`google-chrome --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:6162" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND , EXCLUDE localhost, EXCLUDE 192.168.178.0/24" --proxy-bypass-list="127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1,localhost:3000,localhost,192.168.178.0/24"`

Can anyone reproduce this? 
Any explanation?

P.S. As usually, while writing this, it occurred to me, that the browser might try to reach the proxy at localhost through the proxy itself, but that does not make any sense, does it?